# Angular HttpInterceptor not changing header

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I wrote an angular (4.3.6) HttpInterceptor to add some header fields, but the header doesn't get updated if I inspect them in the debugger. Any idea?

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {


    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        console.log('AuthInterceptor at work');

        const contentTypeReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        });

        const token  = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            const authReq = contentTypeReq.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
            });
            return next.handle(authReq);
        }

        // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
        return next.handle(contentTypeReq);
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the content-type is useless. Angular does that for you. Have you run your code using the debugger? Or just added console.log() to check that the token is set?

Comment: Yes - I ran it in the debugger and see that its beeing called. But the header is not updated. See https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-new-headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are lazy. For example [`keys` method](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/common/http/src/headers.ts#L103) looks like:

```typescipt
keys(): string[] {
    this.init(); <== initialize

    return Array.from(this.normalizedNames.values());
}
```

If you want to check them just call:

```typescipt
req.headers.keys()
```

If you want to check value you can use `get` or `getAll` method:

```typescipt
req.headers.getAll('Content-Type')
```

Or you can call `init` method from console and then you will be able to see headers in `headers` Map

[image]

Moreover when [angular adds headers to request](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L92) it uses [forEach](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/common/http/src/headers.ts#L209) method that calls `init` method too.

Comment: can we update those headers ... for eg In request i sent `'x-auth-token'` and if 401 occurs then I want to update headers .. Is it possible ? for more info ref : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200491/request-header-is-not-updated-successfully-from-interceptor-angular-2-4-401-han]