# Request Header is not updated successfully from interceptor angular 2/4 (401 handling)

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am working with Http interceptor and trying to retry the failed request to handle `401 error`. I am trying to set a new header to update the request but it's not working.

I noticed that My header is not being set with the request instead it's going to the `lazyUpdates` inside headers. Can anyone provide me the any idea why it's happening. After checking my networks I found that with the retry request old header is passed which is `'x-auth-token'` and new headers are not sent.

interceptor.ts

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'x-auth-token': this.authService.getToken()
            }
        });

        return next.handle(request).do(event => {}, err => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status == 401) {

                request = request.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'sample-auth'
                    }
                });

                return next.handle(request)
            }
        });
    }
```

Header that contains values in lazy loading instead of headers:

[image: Here is the header that is being sent with the request]

I have already gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202208/angular-4-interceptor-retry-requests-after-token-refresh)

Any ideas?

I am still having same issue. would anyone please suggest me what can be done to update headers properly.

Comment: Any solutions ??

Comment: Any Solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with cloning of the request. You need to do something like this.

```
request = request.clone({
     headers: request.headers.set("Authorization", `sample-auth`)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine to me, try do like this:

```
export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  // Add your logic to modify headers, e.g., adding an authorization token
  const modifiedRequest = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer yourAuthToken`
    }
  });

return next.handle(modifiedRequest);
}
```

I hope that works to you.