# How can I get HttpParams values as JSON object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular 5 with HttpInterceptors.
I already know  I can get each value I want from `HttpParams` [*via several methods*](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/how-to-pass-url-parameters-query-strings-angular/).

Also -  If I want to see all values  , I can use the `.toString()` method

```
params = new HttpParams()
    .set('page', '2')
    .set('sort', 'name');

console.log(params.toString()); //Returns page=2&sort=name
```

But in my case I send json objects as  parameters :

```
{
  a:1 , b:[1,2,3] , c:[{...}]
}
```

I'm using interceptors to log the request parameters  , but when I `JSON.stringify(req.Params)` , I get :

```
Params={
    "updates": null,
    "cloneFrom": null,
    "encoder": {},
    "map": {}
}
```

Which doesn't expose the values.

I *don't* want to see the parameters as a regular form post parameters -( it will be very unclear), but as an object as I've sent it.

**Question:**

How can I extract the parameters from the request object in the interceptor , but as json format :

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
    {
       JSON.stringify( req.params)  // <--- ?? doesn't yield the params.
   }
```

Comment: can you post how you add those objects to the `HttpParams` object?

Comment: @messerbill **SURE** https://i.imgur.com/Sgn3Ak8.jpg

Comment: That's because they are lazy. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418746/angular-httpinterceptor-not-changing-header/46418968#46418968

Comment: @yurzui Hi. If so  , how can I eagerly extract them as Json.stringify ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir This helps 0.

Comment: @messerbill Why ? I 've showed you how I send the parameters ... no ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir no you posted method definitions...

Comment: @messerbill Oh ok - this is the actual invocation  ( sample) : https://i.imgur.com/EelSQU8.jpg

Comment: update your code instead of posting images.....somebody with 68k Rep should know this.

Comment: @messerbill Because(!) it doesn't relate  the the question. the parameters *are there* , it's just that I can't extract them. And it's not relates to reputation.Why does it matter how I send them  , if i'm showing that they are already there ???

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(params.keys().map(x =>({ [x]: params.get(x)}) )));`

Comment: Please check my answer with example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't like method `toString()` that returns an encoded string, where key-value pairs (separated by `=`) are separated by `&`s you can write your own method that will transform data stored in Map in some data you want to use.

For example:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('page', '2')
  .set('sort', 'name');

const paramsArray = params.keys().map(x => ({ [x]: params.get(x) }));

console.log(JSON.stringify(paramsArray));
```

It's similar to the approach that is used in `toString` method 
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L177-L186

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/WzfTiSlG9Qa2Ciik0tbQ)**

Comment: Oh my god I was so wrong. [I send POST so I should've investigate `req.body` and not `req.params`](https://i.imgur.com/eTvhF9I.jpg) . thank you yurzui. Like always. ( _btw it worked without looping , straight json.stringify on req.body.params_)

Comment: Do  you know the reason for why `req.body.params`  is not lazy , while `req.params` is ? It doesn't make any sense ( to me)

Comment: `Bodies are not enforced to be immutable, as they can include a reference to any
   user-defined data type. However, interceptors should take care to preserve
   idempotence by treating them as such.` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L80-L86

Comment: Oh  , it's jsut copy paste char from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=thank+you+unicode&rlz=1C1NHXL_iwIL704IL704&oq=thank+you+unicode&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2934j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 5):

What you actually requested was a JSON Object. So this is how you get such an object:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('page', '2')
  .set('sort', 'name');

const paramsObject = params.keys().reduce((object, key) => {
    object[key] = params.get(key)
    return object
}, {})
console.log(paramsObject)
// And json if you really want
const json = JSON.stringify(paramsObject)
```